# Restoring local Git repo PC from network share

Tags: git

Super simple I'm sure but I just can't wrap my head around it.  My computer failed which housed my git software.  I have a remote git repository that I pushed changes to.  I can't figure out exactly how to retrieve that remote repository back to my local computer since I have reinstalled git.  For starters.....do I recreate a folder on my computer and run "git init" within that or "git init bare"?  Also, would I clone the remote repo or would I merge or???

Comment: You need to `git clone`

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  So I'm obviously  a noob when it comes to Git but I'm learning.......I wouldn't run "git init" on the local folder that I need the data in first correct?  Just run something like "git clone /myshare:to whatever folder-name"  And just out of curiosity....... could I just copy and paste from the share to my local drive and that do the same thing or no?

Comment: No you do not need to `init`. Just use `git clone`, it will create the new folder and copy the repository into it.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to get the URL of the repository 
(if you are on github you can find it on the repository page)

And then just enter:

```
git clone <remote url>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) the repository.

```
git clone <Remote repo's URL>
```

The URL must follow the ssh, git, http, https or ftp (deprecated!) protocol. It can also be a local file, if the `-l` flag is used.